# Published APK on Google Play with debug keystore

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, android-keystore

as the title, I dont know how but I have updated (2 years ago) an app to Google Play **signed only with the debug keystore** obtained in Android Studio.

This is the screen of a keytool of the apk I have now on the Google Play Store (live version):
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtNAf.png)

As you can see, "Android Debug" and not my name as CN. 
How is this even possible? Before the final publishing I have made a beta phase, maybe loading the app signed with debug keystore in beta and than passing the app to "live" lets you bypass the Google Play control on the keystore?

Now I need to update my app but Google Play prevent the upload because:

1. Now is asking to a signed-by-me APK and not a debug signed APK;
2. It say that the SHA1 code is different  from the APK loaded 2 years ago.

Please help me!

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to contact Google.  There's nothing we can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all a debug key is still a valid key, at least in the past it was and probably even now google didn't do anything to filter out the keys....

You can try to contact google, but I am 100% sure they won't let you change the key.
The only option would be to find the key you signed the app with, or publish it as a new app (new package name).

Even if you try to use the google app signing on their side, first you need to upload the current key